# Git integration with Intellij Idea 9.0.4 not working

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea 9.0.4 on a Mac. I'm having trouble getting the Git Integration plugin to work at all.

So far I have done the following:

1. Cloned a new repro from github by selecting "Check out from version control"  --This worked fine.
2. Go to File => Other Settings => Configure plugins  --The git plugin is enabled and I disabled all others.
3. Go to File => Settings => Version Control => VCSs => Git  --My git executable tests fine and I'm using the native SSH executable.

When I try to use command-t or command-k nothing happens. All the files that I edit are red, indicating that they are not being tracked.

Am I missing something? It seems other people have it working just by enabling the plugin. Should I just convince my company to upgrade to Idea 10.5?

Comment: Try 10.5 trial and see if it works for you. Note that native ssh will not work if your key has a passphrase, it's a known issue.

Comment: Ok I tried the trial of 10.5.2 and it doesn't work either. I was able to clone and see what's going on in the version control console but after it clones I still can't commit or update. If I restart Idea, I can't even get the version control console to show up. It's greyed out in the 'Window=>Tool Windows' menu. This is the same for both 9.0.4 and 10.5.2. Maybe this is happening because I'm using Lion, I haven't seen too many compatibility issues.

Comment: Does it work with IntelliJ IDEA SSH instead of native? Do you have passphrase set for the key?

Comment: It doesn't work with native or idea ssh. But it clones with both. I do not have a passphrase set up for the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! Seems like I've been answering a few of my own questions lately. Makes me wonder if I've been developing better diagnostic skills or just asking dumber questions... Nonetheless, I got it to work by configuring the correct directory in the VCS settings. The root directory of my project was defaulted to use SVN.

DUMB!!